# ng-click doesn't call the function in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The ng-click in the following template code doesn't invoke the function `loginFacebook()` in the controller? The text 'loginFacebook...' is not printed in Javascript console.

**slogin.html**

```
<ion-view title="Login" id="page100">
    <ion-content>
        <a class="button" ng-click="loginFacebook()">
            Sign In With Facebook
        </a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller:**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['client', function ($scope, $state, client) {
    $scope.loginFacebook = function () {
        console.log('loginFacebook...')
        client.login("facebook").then(function succes(data){
            console.log('logged in succesfully..')
            $state.go('menu.events');
        }, function(error){
            console.log('login failed.');
        });
    };
}])
```

**routes.js**

```
  .state('menu.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        'side-menu21': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/slogin.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing **`$scope`** and **`$state`** in the order of injection

Your controller should be,

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$state','client', function ($scope, $state, client) {
        $scope.loginFacebook = function () {
            console.log('loginFacebook...')
            client.login("facebook").then(function succes(data){
                console.log('logged in succesfully..')
                $state.go('menu.events');
            }, function(error){
                console.log('login failed.');
            });
        };
    }])
```